# Build large string in VBA with quotes

Tags: json, excel, vba

I need to build a large string (json) in VBA with quotes in it.

I tried this approach:

```
Dim payload As String
payload = ""
payload = payload & CHR(34) & {"timeframeId":13,"startDate":"2021-05-31 00:00:00.000","endDate":"2021-05-31 00:00:00.000","peopleList":[{"id":123}], & CHR(34)
...more lines building string
```

But the Excel IDE for VBA complains of a syntax error - presumeably to do with the quoted strings?

Do I need to add CHR(34) before the opening and after closing " of each?

Comment: You just need to **escape** the double-quotes within the quoted phrase, with an extra double-quote.  Eg `payload & "{""timeFrameID"":13,""startDate"";""2021-05-31 00:00:00.000""....}"`

Comment: There has to be a better way to build large json strings in VBA. This looks messy at the moment!

Comment: There is. But this is what you showed, and what your question was about.  In Excel, I'd take a look at [VBA-JSON v2.3.0
 (c) Tim Hall](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) for converting objects (Dictionary/Collection/Array) to JSON strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al Grant!

Chr(39) or " double quote char is the text qualifier to VBA, so you need to do an ajustment to use in the strings.

I presume you have this value anywhere in the worksheet.
So the common way to do this is set the range and use replace to another char, and after all back to chr(39).

If you what to input in hardcode, you will need to concatenate chr(39) with everytime a doublequote appears, or use ""

But the easiest way is to replace find and replace (CTRL+H) to another char, and continue to develop like you was doing

```
Dim payload As String
payload = payload & Chr(34) & Replace("{'timeframeId':13,'startDate':'2021-05-31 00:00:00.000','endDate':'2021-05-31 00:00:00.000','peopleList':[{'id':123}],", Chr(39), Chr(34)) & Chr(34)

Debug.Print payload
```

Result:
"{"timeframeId":13,"startDate":"2021-05-31 00:00:00.000","endDate":"2021-05-31 00:00:00.000","peopleList":[{"id":123}],"

Comment: The payload is being sent off to another server - I am not sure if it will accept ' instead of " - I will test and let you know.

Comment: Anyway, if is not hardcode is even easier, just point to the desired range.